# Pushing a DotnetCliTool console project to nuget lists it's project dependencies as package dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-core, csproj, dotnet-cli

I have solution with following projects.

> MyAppNameSpace.Cli [This is the CLI app which is pushed as DotnetCliTool tonuget]
>
> MyAppNameSpace.Core [This project is referenced by the CLI tool]
>
> MyAppNameSpace.Common [Common Project shared in the solution]
>
> MyAppNameSpace.Vsix [Visual studio extension]

What I am trying to achieve is to push the CLI project as a DotnetCliTool to nuget. I have followed whats mention [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/extensibility#how-to-extend-cli-tools). I could not find any sample of dotnet cli tool projects with references to another project in a solution.

The problem is when I do a `nuget push` after doing `dotnet pack`. The package is succesfully pushed to nuget but its project dependencies are listed as package dependencies. So when I reference this tool as a DotnetClitToolReference in any project it starts looking for those dependent projects on Nuget which obviously do not exist.

This is my csproj for the CLI project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>dotnet-nmg</AssemblyName>
    <Authors>Nabin Karki Thapa</Authors>
    <Version>1.0.2</Version>
    <Description>
      The CLI tool for NModelsGenerator, a visual studio extension to create POCO classes from Database Tables and Views.
    </Description>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <Copyright>Nabin Karki Thapa</Copyright>
    <PackageTags>dotnet cli tool</PackageTags>
    <PackageType>DotnetCliTool</PackageType>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/nabinked/NModelsGenerator</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageLicenseUrl>https://github.com/nabinked/NModelsGenerator/blob/master/LICENSE</PackageLicenseUrl>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/nabinked/NModelsGenerator</RepositoryUrl>
    <RepositoryType>git</RepositoryType>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>More information is available at https://github.com/nabinked/NModelsGenerator </PackageReleaseNotes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NModelsGenerator.Common\NModelsGenerator.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\NModelsGenerator.Core\NModelsGenerator.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PostcompileScript" AfterTargets="Pack" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">
    <Exec Command="call nugetpush $(Configuration) $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/bin/$(Configuration)/$(AssemblyName).$(Version).nupkg" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

What am I doing wrong ? There is very little documentation available online on this topic. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Pushing a DotnetCliTool console project to nuget lists it's project dependencies as package dependencies

You did not do anything wrong. This is a known issue about dotnet pack not including reference projects. This is something will definitely address in a future release.

See [Allow project reference DLLs to be added to the parent nupkg for pack target like IncludeReferencedProjects in nuget.exe](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891#issuecomment-330668337) for some more details.

The current workaround is using a custom msbuild target to do that as **dasMulli** described in [#3891 (comment)](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891#issuecomment-330668337):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);IncludeP2POutput</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\testprivatelib\testprivatelib.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="IncludeP2POutput">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="$(OutputPath)\testprivatelib.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help . I tried it, but did not work. I guess I will leave this on a hold till the time the issues is officially resolved.